# Max users to receive emails in Google Groups

Tags: email, google-groups

How can I get more than 100 users to receive emails from my Google Group? Can a contact group be used as an alias user in a Google Group?

Comment: You can send email to more than 100 users with a Google Group.

Answer (score 1):

Ask people to join the group by themselves or wait few days and add another 100 email addresses, then repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the limit by upgrading your account:

[image: 0]

- **https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas**
- **https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en&dark=1**